# PHP - document.xml to document.pdf

Tags: php, xml, pdf, pdf-generation

Here is my problem: I search the best practice to generate a PDF file from a XML file.
I have a document in XML format from Microsoft Word and I would like to know how can I generate a PDF from my XML in PHP.

For the moment I already try xml2pdf but it's not really clear for me... I need only to change the format from XML to PDF.

Currently I know how to modify the content of my XML and after opening it in WORD.
But I don't have any positive results for a PDF.

Do you have any ideas for the best practice to generate a PDF file with PHP ?
Maybe FPDF?

Comment: You're asking for a tool/library that renders OpenXML as PDF. This is not "changing the format". OpenXML is one of the most complex data formats using XML syntax internally.

Comment: your question is "how to use xml2pdf for converting xml to pdf file?" or generally "any solution to convert the xml file into pdf? The XML [line HTML] could be edited with any text editor but the pdf file is a different story. Make your question more clear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After multiple test I used several libraries in PHP:
 - FPDF it's ok to generate a simple PDF with a lot of X and Y axes
 - HTML2PDF for me is the best solution! Why? Because you can create a good page with HTML and after export your page in PDF.

Bye ;)